# Push next DIV down when content overlap in position relative / absolute

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML (Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nL3tc7vw/2/):

```
<div class="parent">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x80?text=Image">

  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.
  </div>

</div>

<div class="next">
  Next div ...
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
}

div.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

div.next {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

How to prevent "Parent" DIV to overlap "Next" DIV when "Child" DIV content height is bigger then image's height?

Basically I need the Text in Child to be over the Image and not overlap the next div.

Comment: Position the img absolutely, not the child div. Then set a min-height on the parent div the size of the img. Or, use the img as a background for the child div.

Comment: @MrLister Then the image gets on top of text or am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/vzj1wu4m/

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited by original question to make clear that I need the text to be over the image and not overlap the next div.

Comment: Then MrLister has given you the answer... other than `z-index`. Personally, I'd use a background image though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the z-index to correct overlapping, you need to add a Position layer to what your trying to do. I've added a "position: relative" to the div.child class. This way the IMG is behind the first div and doesn't overlap the container text. Look at the example below:

I would presume ***@Mr Lister*** had an impact on this answer by adding a position: absolute to the img container to control its current position.

```css
div.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

div.child {
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 2000;
}

div.next {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x80?text=Image">
  
  <div class="child">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.
  </div>

</div>

<div class="next">
  Next div ...
</div>
```